# How to enable stats in RabbitMQ management UI

Tags: rabbitmq

I am running RabbitMQ inside a container on localhost; my /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf is pretty straightforward:

```
loopback_users.guest = false
listeners.tcp.default = 5672
management.tcp.port = 15672
management.disable_stats = false
```

I can access management ui with no problem (as a default guest user), but I see no graphs and stats on an Overview tab. And when I enter Channels tab there is only a message:

```
Stats in management UI are disabled on this node
```

What can be the reason of this behaviour?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I encountered exactly the same problem today.
If you are using rabbitmq inside a container, make sure you are using the correct image, as stated in their [website](https://www.rabbitmq.com/download.html):

`docker run -it --rm --name rabbitmq -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3-management`.

The `rabbitmq_management` plugin is enabled by default.

I was using `docker run -it --rm --name rabbitmq -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq`. I had to manually turn on the management plugin and I encountered your problem.

The reason is that the default image disables metrics collector in the management_agent plugin:

```
# cat /etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/management_agent.disable_metrics_collector.conf 
management_agent.disable_metrics_collector = true
```

For deployment, you could turn it on or off through the configuration file. The instruction could be found [HERE](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#disable-stats).

Comment: Well, adding management_agent.disable_metrics_collector doesn't work for me, but using rabbitmq:3-management does. Thanks a lot!

Comment: changing the config worked for me, I had to restart my container for the changes to take place

Answer (score 5):

```
cd  /etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/
echo management_agent.disable_metrics_collector = false > management_agent.disable_metrics_collector.conf
```

then restart docker container
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuvtL.jpg)

Comment: it works, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a config-file in the docker-container which disables metrics

```
root@rabbitmqcontainer:/etc/rabbitmq/conf.d# ls -1
management_agent.disable_metrics_collector.conf <<<<<<<<<<<<

root@rabbitmqcontainer:/etc/rabbitmq/conf.d# cat  manage*.conf
management_agent.disable_metrics_collector = true
```

I overwrote this config by copying a file the a name at the end of the alphabet
in my Dockerfile:

```
COPY data/etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/zzz_enable_stats.conf ​/etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/
```

The content of the file is

```
management_agent.disable_metrics_collector = false
```

This overrides the config to the value I wish. I think all the config-files
in the directory are worked off by alphabet.